# Changing my callbacks, promise to async await

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, async-await

My code:

**Callbacks:**

```
const first = () => {
  console.log('first');
};
const second = (callback) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('second');
    callback();
  }, 2000);
};
const third = () => {
   console.log('third');
};

first();
second(third);   OUTPUT: 'first', 'second', 'third'
```

**Promises:**

```
const first = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('first');
});
const second = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('second');
  }, 2000);
});
const third = () => {
  console.log('third');
};

first()
 .then((firstPromiseValue) => {
   console.log(firstPromiseValue);
   second()
    .then((secondPromiseValue) => {
      console.log(secondPromiseValue);
      third();
    })
 });   OUTPUT: 'first', 'second', 'third'
```

**Promise all:**

```
const first = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('first');
});
const second = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('second');
  }, 2000);
});
const third = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('third');
});
Promise.all([first, second, third]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
}); OUTPUT: ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

**Async Await:**

How to convert this above code using async await?

Which is the good flow control for javascript applications?

What about some async library which uses methods like async.waterfall, etc..

By the way, is my above code is ok or not?

Comment: Your `first` and `third` things/functions should not have anything to do with promises, there is nothing asynchronous about them.

Comment: if i dont write new Promise for first function, then how .then() will work?

Comment: It wont: it's not needed. You just write `first(); second().then(third);` or `first(); await second(); third();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to convert this above code using async await?

`async/await` is not a replacement for promises, it is a replacement for `then()` and `catch()`. You'd still be using promises. So you'd take the `first`, `second` and `third` definition from your Promises section, and then:

```
async function firstSecondThird() {
  let firstPromiseValue = await first();
  console.log(firstPromiseValue);
  let secondPromiseValue = await second();
  console.log(secondPromiseValue);
  third(); // not a promise, no need to await
}
firstSecondThird();
```

> Which is the good flow control for javascript applications?

Objectively, none of them are better; but `async/await` is the most readable, callbacks the most explicit (with `then` code being in the middle).

> What about some async library which uses methods like async.waterfall, etc..

Promises generally do everything those libraries do, and also got selected to be standardised. You may forget about those libraries unless you are maintaining old code that requires them.

> By the way, is my above code is ok or not?

It seems to do what you want it to do, more or less, without obvious problems in efficiency or legibility. I'd say it's OK.

Answer (score -1):

> How to convert this above code using async await?

Using `async/await` is another way to use Promises. It's most nice visualy because you don't lost in `then/catch` but you can use it. Here you have two examples. First one with then and second one without.

```js
const first = async (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('first ');
  });
};
const second = async (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(value + 'second ');
  });
};
const third = async (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(value + 'third');
  });
};


first('').then(second).then(third).then( value => console.log(value) );
```

---

```js
const first = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('first ');
  });
};
const second = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('second ');
  });
};
const third = () => {
  return 'third';

};

async function main() {
  
  let firstValue = await first();
  
  let secondValue = await second();
  
  let thirdValue = third();
  
  return  firstValue + ' ' + secondValue + ' ' + thirdValue;
}

main()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(err => { console.log('Error:', err) });
```

> Which is the good flow control for javascript applications?

Normally when you need to use Promise in the middle of a function or multiple async calls fo functions.

> What about some async library which uses methods like async.waterfall, etc..

I don't know about any library to use async/await. Sorry!